# How does Google Translate provide offline translations?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

The thing I am specifically puzzled by is how each language corresponds to a single translation file. This means that there must be a common intermediate translation that connects the different languages to solve the NxM problem. How exactly does it work?

Comment: https://research.google.com/pubs/pub45610.html

Comment: @ThomasJungblut this helped, thanks!